# Plotting equation of motion in mathematica

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, wolfram-physics

Suppose I have an equation of a moving body in Newtonian Mechanics e.g.
$ax^2=(b/t^4)+(c/t^2)$
how can I plot a x-t graph in mathematica with a range for the constants a, b and c from 0 to 5 with interval 0.5?
please suggest some help.

Comment: `t` is discontinue at `0`.

Comment: Generate a `Table` of equations and use ``Plot`.

Comment: Are sure that you want 1000 plots?

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

You probably want to use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) with a [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html)

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[
  Evaluate@
   Table[a*x^2 == b/t^4 + c/t^2, {c, 0, 5, 0.5}],
  {t, 0.1, 5}, {x, 0, 5},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[
    LineLegend[Range[0, 5, 0.5],
     LegendLabel -> Style["c =", 14, Bold],
     LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}],
    {.7, .7}],
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"t", "x"}),
  PlotPoints -> 25,
  MaxRecursion -> 5],
 {{a, 1}, 0.5, 5, 0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 1}, 0, 5, 0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot...